# pySerial receives as ASCII how to convert into integer?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am using pySerial to talk to an MSP430 module. This module is transmitting over serial and I am using pySerial to read (as in com.read(20) ). But the type of what pyserial receives is ascii. So when I send out 0x37 from the MSP430 it receives it as '7' and all this is then given to me as a string something like "7☺7" for [0x37 0x1 0x37]. How do I retrieve my data in the same array format I intend. The next step is to plot it using pylab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpack the data with [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html):

```
>>> import struct
>>> data = '\x37\x01\x37'
>>> struct.unpack('!BBB', data)
(55, 1, 55)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, worked like a charm (better maybe)